# Is there a way to grab Outlook calendar start times for recurring events in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook

In Powershell, I am trying to get start times of calendar entries from my Outlook - this works fine except for recurring appointment, the date populated appears to be from when the recurring event was initially created. Is there a way to get the calendar date entry, as opposed to when the recurring event was first entered in? I may be using the incorrect property;

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application

$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
$Calendar = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderCalendar
$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($Calendar).items
#$folder.IncludeRecurrences = $True

$StartWeek = '02/12/2019'
$StartWeekDT = [datetime]::ParseExact($StartWeek,'dd/MM/yyyy', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
$EndWeekDT = $StartWeekDT.AddDays(5)
$Start = $StartWeekDT.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy') + " 00:00"
$End = $EndWeekDT.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy') + " 00:00"

$Filter = "[Start]>= '$Start' AND [End] <= '$End'"
$data = $Folder.Restrict($filter) | Select-Object
```

So here you can see that the filter says that the start property must be greater than 02/12 - which does pick up the recurring event entry. However, when I attempt to view the start property, it shows a date from January (when it was created) instead. I cannot see the correct date in any of the properties, and I've tried setting IsRecurring to false (to see if it would recreate the entry with the correct start) and by using .IncludeRecurrences as suggested by a few online articles, but no luck. Has anyone had this issue before?

```
05/12/2019 10:30:00
05/12/2019 10:00:00
05/12/2019 15:00:00
02/12/2019 16:30:00
03/12/2019 11:00:00
04/12/2019 16:00:00
05/12/2019 15:30:00
05/12/2019 16:30:00
14/01/2019 08:30:00
11/01/2019 16:30:00
16/01/2019 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not figure out how to get the 'just this occurrence' start property, so I just found the start value a different way by adding on 7 days (from the recurring start date) until it was within my search scope, then assigned this to the $entry.start variable - for further processing. Note that this does not amend the calendar entry, but just updates $entry.start to the value within the week after the property has already been pulled. I can then query to see if it was on a monday, tuesday, etc.

```
Foreach($Entry in $data){    

IF ($Entry.Start -lt $EndWeekDT){
        for($i = $Entry.Start; $i -le $EndWeekDT; $i = $i.AddDays(7))
        {
        $Entry.Start = $i
        }
        }

etc..
}
```